# How to show only the indicator in TabLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout

I use [Android Tab Example](https://github.com/InnovateCode/Android-Tab-Example) for navigation.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_above="@+id/lay_bot"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tabIndicatorColor"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
```

And i have next tabs:
[image]

But, i don't know how to show tabs indicator only (without text of tabs). For exampe:[image]

If you know how to do it, can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace following line

```
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

With

```
android:layout_height="6dp"
```

And make sure that u don't provide tab names.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the height as same as indicator height and pass empty `String` as page title(Not neccesary).

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="6dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/lay_bot"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tabIndicatorColor"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
    app:tabTextColor="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
```